# Test parameter for char at end of line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried a number of ways (e.g. "$", "\n") to match
a character at the end of a line (eol).  '+', '-', '*'
and ''.
I do NOT want to match if the character is somewhere
within the string.

Using regex with the characters explicitly is easy.
Stackoverflow answers how for multiple example
questions.  However, I cannot figure it out if the
character is passed as a parameter. How can this be
done?

See the code below.

Thank you

```
import re

def param_not_at_eol(param):
    mystring = "8+8"

    matched = re.search(re.escape(param + '$'), mystring)

    if matched:
        print(f"Matched a {param} but did not want to!")
    else:
        print(f"Did not match {param}. Good.")

def param_at_eol(param):
    mystring = "8+"

    matched = re.search(re.escape(param + '$'), mystring)

    if matched:
        print(f"Matched a {param} and wanted to!")
    else:
        print(f"Did not match {param}. Bad.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    param_not_at_eol("+")
    param_at_eol("+")

# Results:
# Did not match +. Good.
# Did not match +. Bad.
```

Comment: Thank you wjandrea.  That was the answer.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `re.escape(param + '$')`. This makes it try to match a literal dollar sign character `$`. Switch it to: `re.escape(param) + '$'`.